# Hide errors displaying PowerShell for sharepoint

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I want to supress displaying error messages on a certain bloc of code in powershell.

I know that `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` supress error displaying, but it only goes with a cmd-let, in my case i have instructions dealing with variables and affecting some values so i can't use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Here is an example of my code :

```
foreach ($sub in $subsites)
            {
                $subName=$sub.GetAttribute("name")
                $subDescription=$sub.get_InnerText()
                $subUrl=$sub.getAttribute("url")
                $subTerm=$term.CreateTerm($subName,1033) 
                $subTerm.SetDescription($subDescription, 1033) 
                $subTerm.CreateLabel("MOAD_SubTerm", 1033, $false) 
                $termStore.CommitAll()
            }
```

I want to hide errors ONLY for this part of the code , not for the whole file.

How can i do this please?

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968456/how-can-i-supress-error-messages-on-a-certain-bloc-of-code-in-powershell

Comment: Will using the standard try-catch block in power shell work for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try changing the value of the `$ErrorActionPreference`
>   variable:
>
> ```
> $errpref = $ErrorActionPreference #save actual preference
> $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
> ...
> your code
> ...
> $ErrorActionPreference = $errpref #restore previous preference
> ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968456/how-can-i-supress-error-messages-on-a-certain-bloc-of-code-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Although the approach suggested by @Karthik Jaganathan definitely works, I would prefer a try/catch based solution, as it has no sence executing further steps in the loop after a former step has already failed

See the PowerShell error handling strategies on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx)

```
#save actual preference
$errpref = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

foreach ($sub in $subsites)
{
  Try
  {

    $subName=$sub.GetAttribute("name")
    $subDescription=$sub.get_InnerText()
    $subUrl=$sub.getAttribute("url")
    $subTerm=$term.CreateTerm($subName,1033) 
    $subTerm.SetDescription($subDescription, 1033) 
    $subTerm.CreateLabel("MOAD_SubTerm", 1033, $false) 
    $termStore.CommitAll()
  }
  Catch
  {
    # Do nothing in this case
  }
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $errpref
```

Comment: Just to add to this; you should add $erroractionPrefernce = "stop" to your try block and then change it back to "continue" in a finally block otherwise the catch block will never be reached.

Comment: Thanks your comment @Bunzab, I have included $ErrorActionPreference now in my sample code.